# aggregation mongodb and deprecation warning. node js and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, telegram-bot

so I keep getting deprection warnings when trying to send something. what am i missing?

```
bot.on(/show best highscore of: (.+)/, (msg, props) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true } , function(err, db) {
    db.db("mydb").collection("highscores").aggregate([{$group:{'_id':'$name', 'max':{$max:'$highscore'}}}]).toArray(function (err, res){
      if (err) throw (err);
      console.log(res); //everything is fine
      return bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, bd); //i get deprecation warnings etc.
      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: forget the props btw

Comment: what is `bot`? It doesn't look like anything mongodb related... also you have `db.close()` after your `return` so it'll never be called

Comment: bot is referring to the telegram bot

Comment: i got it nevermind